# Moveit! tutorials on ROS Melodic

Tags: moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am trying to install Moveit! on new ROS distro (Melodic).
I think I've done it successfully, but now I am trying to follow the tutorials to get started with moveit!
I am in [Getting Started](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/getting_started/getting_started.html) but in the step "Build your Catkin Workspace" with the instructions

```
cd ~/ws_moveit/src
rosdep install -y --from-paths . --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic
```

I get this:

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
panda_moveit_config: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [franka_description]
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

---

Edit: Thank you very much! I've completed [Getting Started](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/getting_started/getting_started.html) with no errors.
Still, I'm not able to launch moveit! quickstart ([Moveit! Quickstart in RViz](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/quickstart_in_rviz/quickstart_in_rviz_tutorial.html))

When launch it with tutorial instrcution I get:

```
Resource not found: franka_description
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/melodic/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/joao/ws_moveit/src/moveit_tutorials
ROS path [2]=/home/joao/ws_moveit/src/panda_moveit_config
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/melo
```

Which seems strange to me, because I think I've just git -cloned franka_description package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303278/moveit!-tutorials-on-ros-melodic/) by [joao](https://answers.ros.org/users/34862/joao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-09-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2018-10-18**:
I've created an issue to track this:
https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_tutorials/issues/235

A pull request with a work around would be very welcomed, especially in time for World MoveIt! Day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> panda_moveit_config: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [franka_description]
> ```

The issue here is that while MoveIt itself has seen a first release into Melodic, the `panda_moveit_config` package has not been (see [status_page/compare_kinetic_melodic.html?q=panda](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/compare_kinetic_melodic.html?q=panda), notice how there is no version number listed in the `Melodic` column).

As those packages are a requirement of the tutorial packages that you've `git clone`d into your workspace, `rosdep` will try to install them and fail (seeing as they're not released yet).

What you could try is see whether `git clone`-ing those pkgs to your Catkin workspace and building them from source works. Note though, no guarantee this will work, as the tutorials have not been released for Melodic yet.

The packages that would be needed are:

- [panda_moveit_config](https://github.com/ros-planning/panda_moveit_config)
- `franka_description` in [frankaemika/franka_ros](https://github.com/frankaemika/franka_ros)

**Note**: while `panda_moveit_config` is a simple, no-compilation needed configuration package, the packages in `franka_ros` are packages that contain a lot more. You might want to `CATKIN_IGNORE` or delete all the packages other than `franka_description` after you've `git clone`d the `franka_ros` repository.

After you've added those packages, re-run the `rosdep` command and it should succeed.

Note again: no guarantee this will work, as the tutorials have not been released for Melodic yet.

And note also: if there are more dependencies of the MoveIt tutorials that aren't available in ROS Melodic, then just getting the Panda pkgs doesn't resolve the issue of course.

---

Edit: also just noticed this:

> ```
> rosdep install -y --from-paths . --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic
> ```

Since you are on ROS Melodic, you obviously should specify `--rosdistro melodic` here, *not* `kinetic`.

---

Edit2:

> When launch it with tutorial instrcution I get:

> ```
> Resource not found: franka_description
> ```

```
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/melodic/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/joao/ws_moveit/src/moveit_tutorials
ROS path [2]=/home/joao/ws_moveit/src/panda_moveit_config
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/melo
```

> Which seems strange to me, because I think I've just git -cloned franka_description package.

That is slightly strange.

Did you delete all pkgs except `franka_description` from the `franka_ros` package?

Did you source your `devel/setup.bash` after building the workspace?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3